# Jasmine test case Cannot read property 'close' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I trying to write unit test case for `close` method, but when i do `ng test` i get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
```

Below is my test code

```
describe('CPComponent', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<CPComponent>;
    let component: CPComponent;
    let de: DebugElement;
    let el: HTMLElement;


    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
            declarations: [ CPComponent ],
            imports: [CommonModule, CookieModule.forRoot()],

        });
        TestBed.compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CPComponent);
    });

 it('should close the banner', () => {
        component.close();
        const comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.bwc-o-display-2'));
        el = de.nativeElement;
        expect(el.textContent).toBeUndefined();
      });
```

My Close Method

```
close() {
    this.cpBanner = false;
    this.cookieService.put( 'CP_BANNER', 'true' );
  }
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: where do you define the variable `component`?

Comment: your `component` might not have initialised properly if you're getting error at `component.close()`. check that first.

Comment: I've added full code, I don't see any error in vscode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `component` is never assigned. You also have to change the order of execution. Try this:

```
it('should close the banner', () => {
    component = fixture.componentInstance; // assign component
    component.close(); // use component
    fixture.detectChanges();
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.bwc-o-display-2'));
    expect(de).toBeFalsy();
});
```

Comment: Thanks but i get another error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null`

Comment: I'm guessing that the call to `close()` removes the `'.bwc-o-display-2'` from the DOM. So there is no debugElement and also no nativeElement after the close. I'll update my answer